# Getting context using groovyutils outside SoapUI

Tags: groovy, soapui

I am trying to hold the response of my request in a holder variable but I am not able to.

In SoapUI `groovyutils` is in-built and can be used easily.  But I am sending my soap request using groovy and it is working fine.  Now I want to get the response in a holder and put some assertions.

My piece of code for this is :

```
import com.eviware.soapui.*
def groovyUtils = new com.eviware.soapui.support.GroovyUtils()
def responseHolder = groovyUtils.getXmlHolder( messageExchange.responseContent )
```

Here I am not able to get as how I should pass the context in groovyutils and what all classes to call.

Comment: Why do want to use groovy to send web service while there is soap request step which does easily?

Comment: Did you figure this out? I have the same issue.

I want to use the soapui jar to parse a wsdl and generate a test suite and mock suite using groovy outside soapui. The problem is the I don't have a 'context' when running the script outside soapui. Without a context, I don't have access to groovyUtils and therefore a lot of code doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I fully understand your problem, however seems that you want to check a *SOAP response* out of *SOAPUI* but using the facilities from *SOAPUI* jar isn't it?

If you want simply perform some `assert` in the response, then I would recommend you to avoid the use of `GroovyUtils`. Simply use [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html) to parse the response, then get the desired values from the xml nodes and perform your `asserts`.

Since your *Groovy* code to you invoke the service and the response is missing I simply show you a possible example using [`XmlSlurper`](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/api/groovy/util/XmlSlurper.html):

```
def response = '''<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope/">
<soap:Body>
    <myResponse>
        <someNode>myText</someNode>
    </myResponse>
</soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>'''

def xml = new XmlSlurper().parseText(response)
// find the <someNode> element
def someNode = xml.'**'.find { it.name() == 'someNode' }
// check that the <someNode> has a value equals of 'myText'
assert someNode.text() == 'myText'
```

Hope it helps,